# scipy bilinear transformation incorrect at low frequencies and high sampling rate

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

**EDIT: I think I might have a roundabout way to deal with the issue.**

**Since I'm starting from the zpk representation, just split the higher order filter into two smaller order filters.**

**For example, instead of designing a filter with 5 poles and 5 zeros, design Filter A with three poles and three zeros and Filter B with two poles and two zeros. Then filter with Filter A and then filter with Filter B. This should be equivalent and I tested it at low sampling rates (since at low sampling rates I don't see this issue) seems to have positive results.**

I'm using the scipy.signal module to implement a filter where I designate 5 zeros (all at 100Hz), and 5 poles (all at 1Hz). I'm looking at the frequency response of the digital filter and it doesn't look like the analog filter at low frequencies.

I've noticed that if I lower the sampling rate, then it matches pretty well (eg. lowering from 16384Hz to 4096Hz). Or if I lower the order of the filter, then it matches better too.

Could someone explain how to match the analog and digital frequency responses better?

Example images below.

4096Hz (black: analog filter magnitude, blue: digital filter magnitude) notice some difference at low frequencies:

[image: x]

16384Hz the match a low frequencies is worse:

[image: x]

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define zpk filter and sampling rate
z = np.array([2*np.pi*(-100.), 2*np.pi*(-100.), 2*np.pi*(-100.), 2*np.pi*(-100.), 2*np.pi*(-100.)], dtype=np.float64)
p = np.array([2*np.pi*(-1.), 2*np.pi*(-1.), 2*np.pi*(-1.), 2*np.pi*(-1.), 2*np.pi*(-1.)])
k = 1./ 100.**5
sample_rate = 16384

# get analog coefficients
analog_coefficients = scipy.signal.zpk2tf(z, p, k)

# get digital coefficients
digital_coefficients = scipy.signal.bilinear(analog_coefficients[0], analog_coefficients[1], sample_rate)

# get frequency response
wa,ha = scipy.signal.freqs(analog_coefficients[0], analog_coefficients[1], 2**20)
w,h = scipy.signal.freqz(digital_coefficients[0], digital_coefficients[1], 2**20)
w = w * sample_rate / (2 *np.pi)
wa = wa / (2 *np.pi)


# plot frequency response
# blue  : digital magnitude
# black : analog magnitude
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title('Digital filter frequency response')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.semilogx(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)), 'b')
plt.semilogx(wa, 20 * np.log10(abs(ha)), 'k')
plt.ylabel('magnitude [dB]')
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.grid()
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlim([0.001, sample_rate/2])
plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Given quantisation at low frequency, I would assume that this is a precision issue.

Comment: There's also `from scipy.signal.filter_design import _zpkbilinear` which works as `z, p, k = _zpkbilinear(z, p, k, fs)` and isn't yet a public function because we didn't know what to call it.